# Find number of most points covered after deleting sections

Tags: algorithm, intervals, greedy

first question here, I have algorithms assignment. Generaly, I know it should be greedy algorithm, but could not work out which approach to use. Here is the problem:
N sections are given, which are located on one numerical axis. Each section is described by two integers - the coordinates of the left and right ends and covers the corresponding points. All coordinates are pairwise different. K pieces should be deleted from the existing sections so that the remaining sections cover the maximum number of points in total.

Input
Input data: in the first line two integers - N and K (K≤N≤100000,1≤K≤100). In each of the next N lines, two integers from the range 0..10^9 - the left and right ends of the corresponding section.

Output
Output data: one integer - the maximum number of unit intervals covered by remaining sections.

Note that these sections are overlapping.

As mentioned above, I have tried different greedy approeaches (sorting by start, by end, by length), Connecting to similiar problem of non-overlapping sections, problem of choosing minimum points to cover all intervals. After stackoverflow's suggestions of duplicate questions I found out basically it is Maximum Coverage Problem, but on simple test case it gave incorrect answer, so I doubt it will pass complex test-cases.

Any hint to solution would be appriciated.

Comment: On what basis do you "know" this algorithm should be greedy?

Comment: I assummed because of covered subject in class and as later mentioned,  it is Maximum Coverate Problem, which needs greedy algorithm. Is my assumtion incorrect?

Comment: I'm not too sure if there's a greedy algorithm either. I can only seem to convince myself of the correctness of a recursive/dynamic programming solution, which should run in O(N * K) time.

Comment: Side remark: good first question. You've stated the problem, what you tried, your assumptions, and aren't just asking us to code it for you.